# Is there a way to use a bot, webhook, or some other connector to be notified when someone joins an online Teams Meeting?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-teams

Our company uses Teams Online Meetings extensively.  Teams is a great product and is a wonderful communication tool.  We have a scenario where we need to be notified when a participant joins a Teams meeting, leaves the meeting, or the meeting ends (all participants have left).

Can a bot, webhook, or connector be setup to listen to those events?  Also, these meetings will be dynamically created real-time (not a scheduled event) using the Microsoft Graph API.  Can the bot, webhook or connector be programmatically added to the meeting in order to receive the join, leave and end meeting events?

Thanks for your help,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No...

The problem is that you can think of a "[bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-concept-overview)" as a virtual teams client for a bot user.  So it has the same limitations as a "normal" client (in most cases).  So unless you invite the bot into the call or the bot is already in the call (e.g. started the call) then no you can't do what you want.  If the bot IS in the call already then yes you can do what you want.  The bot can invite, drop participants and end calls.

There is another way, you can create a [Policy Recording Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy) and will automatically insert itself into every call for a user that has the policy set to them.  There is a overhead that the call start up time is a lot greater and all such calls are now conference calls.  So the media is NOT endpoint to endpoint any longer.  See the [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot) for an example of this type of bot.

The other downside would be that Microsoft may not like what you are doing using the Policy Recording Bot for non-recording purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay, Shane.  I'll check into both options.  For option 1, can I invite the bot to the call dynamically, using Microsoft Graph or some other method?

Comment: No, option 1 you will have to invite the bot in MANUALLY yourself per call.  There is NO way to automatically invite it in...  (i.e. the user has to manually add participant, lookup bot and select to be added to the call) Basically teams has no remote CTI support for calls.  Beyond that there is also NO call event API either, so no peace of code has any idea that a user is even on a call, let along call details...  The only way to know you are on a call is using something like presence subscription for a user and see the 'on a call' presence change.

Comment: Thanks Shane, I appreciate your quick response.