# How to add bots to Teams conversations using Recording Policy?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use Microsoft's communications graph API, in order to do that I need the conversations' IDs (for calls and online meetings). The only way I know how to get those is using the bot if it is in the conversation.

According to this post:

[Is there a way to use a bot, webhook, or some other connector to be notified when someone joins an online Teams Meeting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66499949/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-bot-webhook-or-some-other-connector-to-be-notified-whe)

The only way to add a bot to every conversation in the tenant, is using the [Recording Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy). The [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/a3943bafd73ce0df780c0e1ac3428e3de13a101f/Samples/BetaSamples/LocalMediaSamples/ComplianceRecordingBot) that is referenced in the Recording Policy page is outdated and the deployment/publishing via VS is not working. This sample also requires a WC certificate, is this requirement a must for my goal?

I also tried [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp) while applying the Recording Policy to a user, and once I enable the policy the user is no longer able to converse (maybe since this bot does not handle incoming calls). I tried to find out where to handle the incoming calls in the code, but I was unsuccessful.
I would appreciate a working sample or any other solution that would help in my goal.

Comment: Could you please refer this sample (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot)?

Comment: This sample is in my post

Comment: Could you please refer this step by step guide for set up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-calling-and-meeting ? Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT This sample is also in my post, it works but it's not what I asked

Comment: Please refer this sample(https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot) as it doesn't have any package error as compared to the one you are using(https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/a3943bafd73ce0df780c0e1ac3428e3de13a101f/Samples/BetaSamples/LocalMediaSamples/ComplianceRecordingBot) although it looks same